# Using socket.io client with mutliple modules

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io, es6-modules, web-frontend

I have multiple html files and they each have associated js files mainly for DOM manipulations and also socket.io functionality. However, I can't figure out how to have the same socket.id for these different javascript files. I can maybe merge these js files together into one, but that would be a regress.

I tried making a js module `socket.js`:

```
import { io } from 'https://cdn.socket.io/4.3.2/socket.io.esm.min.js';
export const socket = io()
```

and then imported this in my js files, but as I soon realized this wasn't working.

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: the socket is different between the files, Particularly the socket.id

Comment: Put all the code relating to socket.io in one file, load that file in one time. I would also suggest looking into a frontend framework like react for building websites that more complex than simple information slabs

Comment: Each new web page will create a new webSocket connection - those connections do not survive changing pages in a browser - this has nothing to do with your client-side module strategy - it just is the way the browser works.  Thus, every page will have a different `socket.id` when the page loads and that page connects to your server.  You will probably want some sort of server-side session so you can identify which user is which - no matter which socket.id it is and to perhaps keep track of the current `socket.id`.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying the same thing today and came across your question. My solution was this:

main.js is loaded on every page load.
an IIFE runs which sets a variable in my emitter file with the socket via `socket.on('connect', ()=>{})`
It also just runs a function containing all `socket.on(msg,()=>{})`, passing the socket.

I can put all my socket message functions into emitters.js. and all received messages into received.js

I haven't found any issues yet, but I'm not yet sure if this is standard practice. I couldn't find much info on this exact question, so hope this helps.

main.js

```
import socketEmitters from './emitters';
import socketRoutes from './socketRoutes';

(function () {
  const socket = io();

  socketReceived(socket);

  socket.on('connect', () => {
    socketEmitters().getSocketInstance(socket);
  });
}());
```

emitters.js

```
let socket = null;
    
export default function socketEmitters() {

  return {
    emitBtnEvent(toggle, msg) {
      socket.emit(msg, true);
    },

    getSocketInstance(socketReceived) {
      socket = socketReceived;
    }

  };
}
```

received.js

```
export default function socketRoutes(socket) {

  socket.on('receivedMsg', () => {...});

}
```